# Regular expression to display input excluding characters and white spaces using javascript?

Tags: regex

I want to display whatever we inputted to `text-field` excluding special characters and white spaces. Is there any regular expression for that.

For example:- If we given **KA13@B74$5**, then we need to display
**KA13B745**

Comment: `java!=javascript` First make sure what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Remove anything other than you required using a [negated character class regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
console.log(
  'KA13@B74$5'.replace(/[^a-z\d]+/ig, '')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In java code is bit simple

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String input=sc.nextLine();
String newstr="";
for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
{
char ch=input.charAt(i);
if(Character.isLetter(ch)|| Character.isDigit(ch))
{
newstr=newstr+ch;
}

}
System.out.print(newstr);//string without spaces and special characters
```

Comment: This code is written in java i don't know weather cse project wants it in java or javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet

```html
<input type=text onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z\d]+/ig, '')">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'KA13@B74$5'.replace(/[\W]+/ig, '')
```

`\W` is any special character